# Running Swift XCTests on iDevice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest

I have a Swift app that runs fine on both my iPad and the simulator. The project also has a Test target that runs fine on the simulator, but won't run on an iPad or iPhone.

When I try to test on any iDevice, I get linker errors saying:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"__TFC17ExampleApp17ExampleObjectCfMS0_FT_S0_", referenced from:
      __TFC22ExampleAppTests8ExampleTests5setUpfS0_FT_T_ in ExampleTests.o
...
```

In my XCTestCase, I'm importing my main target:

```
import ExampleApp
```

Again, this works for the simulator, but not an actual device. Everything is targeted for iOS 8, and I'm on the newest betas.

Comment: Have you checked if the archtecture is set to the same values for the main target and the testing target?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined symbol errors usually result from code failing to be linked in at compile time – check to make sure all of your relevant `.swift` files are marked to be included in both the ExampleTests target and your ExampleApp target.

Comment: Perhaps not. By default Swift (and current ObjC) uses "application style" tests (TEST_HOST flag is set), meaning that all of the main targets classes and libraries will be visible to the test target. In fact, importing to both can cause namespace errors, making a class appear 'invisible'. . it could in fact be the opposite?

Comment: @Jasper Blues — I suspect the problem isn't in the Swift imports but in the actual object files being linked